# how to Abort/exit/stop/terminate in laravel console command using code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, command

Let's say I'm coding a command. How would I stop it completely in the middle of it running?

Example:

```
public function handle()
{
    if (!$this->good_times) {
        $this->error('Bad times');
        $this->exit();
    }

    // continue command stuff
}
```

I have tried:

```
throw new RuntimeException('Bad times');
```

But that dumps a bunch of ugliness in the terminal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use a **`return`** statement instead of throwing an exception. Like...

```
public function handle()
{
    if (!$this->good_times) {
        $this->error('Bad times');
        // $this->exit();
        // throw new RuntimeException('Bad times');
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Notice that since Laravel 7 console commands must not return void, but only integers. In the example a `return true` should be changed to `return 0`. But stil, only returning something (0 or 1) would do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Ran into this problem as well.

Just create an exception that implements `ExceptionInterface`.

```
use Exception;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\ExceptionInterface;

class ConsoleException extends Exception implements ExceptionInterface
{

}
```

now when you throw the error:

```
throw new ConsoleException('Bad times');
```

You get the error without the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

try to used like that

```
public function handle()
    {
        try {
            if(!isset($x)){
                throw new \Exception('not found');
            }
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }

        $this->info("test here");
    }
```

Comment: I went about doing this in a laravel console command but it causes a issue of exiting the phpunit suite when running phpunit tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function foo()
{
    if (/* exception trigger condition */) {
        throw new \Exception('Exception message');
    }
    // ...
}

public function handle()
{
    try{
        $this->foo();
    } catch (\Exception $error){
        $this->error('An error occurred: ' . $error->getMessage());
    
        return;
    }
    
    $this->comment('All done');
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers already provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return` with the exit code number:

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->error('Invalid parameter: thiswillfail');
    return 1;
}
```

Return a `0` if all is ok, a non-zero positive value on errors:

```
$ ./artisan mycommand thiswillfail; echo $?
Invalid parameter: thiswillfail

1
```

This works with at least Laravel 6 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return` or `exit`  if you want to stop the command from within a function.

```php
public function handle()
{
    return;
}
```

```php
protected function stop() {
    exit;
}
    
public function handle()
{
    $this->stop();
}
```