# Laravel command with options

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I made a command with two options in laravel, first will transfer data and second will delete the data from source `php artisan transfer:db --transfer --delete`. The problem I am facing is if there is some error in my first option which transferring the data, it will still run the second option which in my case will delete the data. I wanted to know that if it possible to exit the whole command if any of them fails at some step

Comment: you can try using 'try catch exceptions'
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557054/how-to-abort-exit-stop-terminate-in-laravel-console-command-using-code

Comment: @archvayu i think this will only stop the current command. a normal return would do the job for that. but I want the whole command to be stopped i.e the next option should not run

Comment: It is not clear for me. Is the command running option by option? As far as I know, executing a command is just running its `handle()` function, and `option`s are used to provide extra arguments to the command.

Comment: @Quicksilver `php artisan transfer:db --transfer --delete` this is my command which is in same handle so the transfer option will run first and if there is some error it will halt the process. I've used **return** tu shut the first option if the error occurs. but the next option which is delete is running after that. i want the whole command to stop but it seems only the first option is being stopped by it

Comment: If you put a `return` in `handle()`, all the code below (including the 'delete' part) should be skipped. Isn't it?

Comment: Can you share your code with us?

Comment: call the next only if first is concluded with no exceptions; add dependency of first command procedure to the second;

Comment: Where is your code? Without seeing that we can only guess what the problem might be.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Don'tPanic i really dont think code is needed here for the concept I want to clear about. I've visited the how to ask page and I know what I am asking here

Comment: @Quicksilver you are right the delete part is not running like I thought